# solution for django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am a student who has recently started with studying databases and Django.

I have been trying to open my Django site, but when I type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it shows me a message at the end saying

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)")

Is there any good solution for this problem? I have been searching for similar problems, but still haven't found a good solution yet.

Comment: All questions about errors need to include the full traceback.

Comment: Make sure Django can connect to the databse that you have defined.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/databases/ maybe this will help you

Comment: which database used??

Answer (score 0):

I think this error was raised with the wrong database configuration please check the configuration here I provided ***(mySql,Postgresql)*** config for `settings.py`

```
# ---- Postgresql ----
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# ---- Mysql ----
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your SQL server.

[Refer this link :](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/start-mysql-server)